# Imgur API upload.json returns XML?

Tags: xml, json, api, url, imgur

so am having a little trouble with the anonymous imgur API.

If I go to http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json - this clearly returns JSON.

If I go to http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?key=ANONAPIKEY&image=http:/ - this also returns a JSON formatted error.

However, If I actually try and upload a valid image, say :

http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?key=ANONAPIKEY&image=http://www.utra.ca/Pictures/Projects/reprap.jpg

this now returns XML.

Could anyone explain this ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your URL before sending it over. This should work, for example:

> http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?key=ANONAPIKEY&image=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.utra.ca%2FPictures%2FProjects%2Freprap.jpg

You can encode your URL in Javascript using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Example:

```
var url = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?key=ANONAPIKEY&image=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.utra.ca/Pictures/Projects/reprap.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks - I did the equivalent in Java :) . The only reason I was stumped was cos it didn't work in the URL bar if I typed it in. I hadn't coded it up cos I thought if it didn't work just typing it into a browser, then it wouldn't work if I coded it up either :P :)